# how do I locate the btn by class name?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this html code:
`<button class="_2ic5v"><span aria-label="Like" class="glyphsSpriteComment_like u-__7"></span></button>`

I am trying to locate all the elements that meet this class with phyton, and selenium webdriver library:
`likeBtn = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_2ic5v')`

but when I print 
`likeBtn`
it prints 
`[]`

I want to locate all of the buttons that much this div/span class, or aria-label

how do I do that successfully? Thanks in advance

update - when I do copy Xpath from page the print stays the same

Comment: Is the class name the same across page requests? If you get all the buttons in the page, is the button you need among them?

Comment: what do you mean by "across page requests"? sorry can't understand that. Yes the btn is among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following Xpath Option This will find the button which contains `aria-label='Like'`.

```
//button[./span[@aria-label='Like' and starts-with(@class,'glyphsSpriteComment_like')]]
```

Code :

```
likeBtn=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[./span[@aria-label='Like' and starts-with(@class,'glyphsSpriteComment_like')]]")
for button in likeBtn:
    button.click()
```

---

**Edited**:

Induce `WebDriverWait`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

likeBtn=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//button[./span[@aria-label='Like' and starts-with(@class,'glyphsSpriteComment_like')]]")))
```

Comment: @RonPetrosian : I guess you are accessing instagram link.Induce `WebDriverWait` and check still you are getting null.

Comment: @RonPetrosian : Check the edited code and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've tried that and still it crash
And yes it is on Instagram. I will just try to do it on different way. It will be longer and more complicated but at least it works

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your problem description, your code should be working just fine. The most likely issue is that your `class` name is dynamic, and changes. You could try using an XPATH that queries on classname instead:

```
likeBtn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, '_2ic5v')]")
print(likeBtn)
```

You may need to change the `_2ic5v` value to something else, depending on your page HTML.

Comment: I've checked and it is the same xpath all the time. I will try your solution thanks!

Comment: @RonPetrosian Appreciate the update. I'm not sure if I can be of any further help based on info. provided in the question -- if you post the HTML for the button you are trying to click (and the elements around it, if possible) then we can try out some different paths. It's possible your button is hidden by an `iframe` element higher in the DOM as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it button class name dynamic or static?

How if you try choose By.CssSelector?

You can find element by copy selector in element

Answer (score 0):

You can try following xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@class='_2ic5v']")
```